Hyper-V manager does not showing virtual machines unless run with administrator
Sometime this week, Hyper-V Manager stopped listing my virtual machines.
Before, I started Hyper-V Manager and the VMs were there, listed, ready to use.
Now, it shows an empty window, with a "Connect to Server..." option. There I can select "Local computer" but it gives and error:
[Window Title]
Hyper-V Manager

[Main Instruction]
An error occurred while attempting to connect to server "myhostname". Check that the Virtual Machine Management service is running and that you are authorized to connect to the server.

[Content]
You do not have the required permission to complete this task. Contact the administrator of the authorization policy for the computer 'myhostname'.

[Close]

If I run Hyper-V Manager as administrator, the everything works as before.
What caused this change?
Well, there were some "improvements" on the PC by IT, but I have no details.
OS : Windows 11 22H2
To summarize: how to start Hyper-V Manager with a single click, but so it shows the VMs?
PS: This question is seems related: Hyper-V-Manager does not show any VMs and the "actions" pane is empty

By default, VMs are only visible to the user that created them. Your VMs were created using your admin account. But... "some improvements on the PC by IT" means you should not be asking us here. You need to talk with your IT. Because you have IT staff, you should be asking them. They will have applied settings that we won't be aware of, and they own the computer, not you, and so they are responsible for the computer, not us.
